# How to include page title of wordpress post in the content possibly with a shortcode

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

in the wordpress admin, i would like to do the following when creating a page:

Page Title: Test

Page content:

Lorem ipsum dolor **[page_title]** sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc et lectus sit amet ante vulputate ultrices at sit amet **[page_title]** tortor. Nam mattis commodo mi in semper. Suspendisse ut eros dolor. Morbi at odio feugiat **[page_title]** nunc vestibulum venenatis sit amet vitae neque. Nam ullamcorper ante ac risus malesuada id iaculis nibh ultrices.

---

Where it says [page_title] I would like it to print the page title (Test)

This needs to be achieved through the admin system, not hard-coded in the template.

Comment: Do you have anythin that you have tried ?

Comment: You can use this plugin as well. https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-content-shortcodes/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Refer to the codex: [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

```
function myshortcode_title( ){
   return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'myshortcode_title' );
```

Add this to your theme's functions.php file.

Note that per the comments exchange between S.Visser and I in his answer - this solution will only work inside The Loop, while his will also work outside The Loop and so his is the more complete answer.

Comment: even more concise, using this as shorter. useful function thank you very much

Comment: @scott btw updated answer to remove $atts parameter as you're not using any short code attributes in this example.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your theme, or make an plugin from it.

```
/* title to get the post title  */
function getPageTitle() {
  global $wp_query;
  return get_post_title($wp_query->post->ID);
}

/* Add shortcode */
add_shortcode('page_title', 'getPageTitle');
```

Comment: Hey you got my +1 by the way. Is this doing anything that my answer won't do? Both will work only if called during the_content from within the loop, yeah?

Comment: Yes both will work in the loop, the one I suggested will also work outside of the loop. `get_the_title` will only work inside.

Comment: Superb. Thanks, S. Visser!

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution on web hope it will help others who face the same problem as mine. Just add the below code to functions.php file or to the page_title plugin .php file.

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'show_shortcode_in_excerpt');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'show_shortcode_in_excerpt');
function show_shortcode_in_excerpt($excerpt) {
    return do_shortcode(wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 55));
}
```