# Use dynamic urls from post page to form page in gutenberg editor

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to use [query parameters to prefill a jetpack contact form](https://jetpack.com/support/jetpack-blocks/contact-form/contact-form-classic-editor/) on a separate page. It's a woocommerce single product template page with a link like this:

```
<a href="/inquiry-page?g1811-original=[post_title]">Inquire</a>
```

I want to dynamically populate the post title (or post id, whatever works) in the url so when I get to the inquiry page it pre-fills the title in the field in the inquiry form:

```
<input type="text" name="g1811-original" value="" placeholder="" required="" aria-required="true">
```

Right now the pre-fill works but the field just says "[post-title]". I'm trying to do this with shortcodes or similar in the Gutenberg editor without resorting to javascript/PHP if possible. Is there a way to use the visual editor or code editor to do this?

EDIT: I've tried using woocommerce shortcodes but they didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I realized `[post_title]` didn't exist, so I created a custom shortcode. For some reason, other woocommerce shortcodes weren't working on the page, so I used [these instructions](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-product-title-shortcode/). I added this through WPCode plugin but here's another [more complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079490/how-to-include-page-title-of-wordpress-post-in-the-content-possibly-with-a-short).

```
/**
  * @snippet       Echo Current Product/Post Name (Shortcode)
  * @usage         Use [post_title] on the current post
  * @compatible    WooCommerce 8
  */

  add_shortcode( 'post_title','get_the_title' );
```

After that inserting `/art-inquiry?g1811-original=[post_title]` in the Gutenberg link editor printed the title of the product into the url `/art-inquiry?g1811-original=The%20Post%20Title` which pre-filled the jetpack form.